# Блокировка кнопки для прокрутки ViewPager

Tags: java, android

У меня есть ViewPager состоящий из двух фрагментов. Я добавил кнопки (`left-right`) для смены фрагментов.

```
   button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
        }
    });


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()-1, true);
        }
    });
```

Как сделать условие при котором, при нашем присутствии на 1 фрагменте блокировалась или исчезала кнопка "left", а при присутствии на 2 фрагменте, кнопка "right"?

Пробовал сделать с помощью `setUserVisbileHint()` в котором c помощью `setVisibility` создавал видимость кнопок, но получилось так что,  если я буду скролить с помощью пальца, то кнопки не будут исчезать и появляться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
            button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

дополнение

```
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    if(position==0){
                       button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                       button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else if(position==1){
                       button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                       button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                    }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            }
```

Comment: но я бы посоветовал использовать TabLayout, вместо Button. и вместо visibility использовать, селекторы. где проставить enabled true and false для бэкграунда и текста

Comment: Это работает, да. Но если я буду скролить с помощью пальца, то кнопки останутся на своих местах. @MaksimKuznecov

Comment: добавил дополнение

Answer (score 0):

Использовать вместо INVISIBLE - GONE? Насколько я понимаю,GONE не просто делает невидимым,а вообще не выделяет место в layout-e под кнопку,следовательно ее как бы и нет